# How to create a virtual environment for python 2.7 using pipenv?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pipenv

```
C:\Users\Abj>python
Python 2.7.15 (v2.7.15:ca079a3ea3, Apr 30 2018, 16:30:26) [MSC v.1500 64 
bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ^Z

C:\Users\Abj>cd Documents\VVV\qq\

C:\Users\Abj\Documents\VVV\qq>pipenv install django
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Pipfile: C:\Users\Abj\Documents\VVV\qq\Pipfile
Using c:\python\python37-32\python.exe (3.7.2) to create virtualenv…
[    ] Creating virtual environment...Already using interpreter 
c:\python\python37-32\python.exe
Using base prefix 'c:\\python\\python37-32'
New python executable in C:\Users\Abj\.virtualenvs\qq- 
bCTw3U33\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.

Successfully created virtual environment!
Virtualenv location: C:\Users\Abj\.virtualenvs\qq-bCTw3U33
Creating a Pipfile for this project…
Installing django…
Adding django to Pipfile's [packages]…
Installation Succeeded
Pipfile.lock not found, creating…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
Success!
Updated Pipfile.lock (4f9dd2)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (4f9dd2)…
================================ 2/2 - 00:00:01
To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.

C:\Users\Abj\Documents\VVV\qq>pipenv run python
Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 
32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ^Z

C:\Users\Abj\Documents\VVV\qq>pipenv shell
Launching subshell in virtual environment…
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

(qq-bCTw3U33) C:\Users\Abj\Documents\VVV\qq>which python
/c/Users/Abj/.virtualenvs/qq-bCTw3U33/Scripts/python

(qq-bCTw3U33) C:\Users\Abj\Documents\VVV\qq>python -V
Python 3.7.2
```

I want to create a virtual environment using python 2.7

Python 3.7.2 was default one in my computer environment. So I changed it in path environment variable to python 2.7.15. After that also while using pipenv, python uses python 3.7.2.

Can anyone help me, how can I use python 2.7.15 in this case?

Answer (score 5):

I got the answer from https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/, need to use command

```
pipenv --two install django
```

Comment: Yes, you need to use the —two flag.

Comment: That flag has already been deprecated. https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4938